# Como pegar a altura da div, arrendonda-la ao múltiplo de 24 mais próximo e aplicar o resultado no style="height" da própria div?

Tags: javascript

Preciso de um script que faça exatamente isso: pegar a altura da `div`, arrendonda-la ao múltiplo de 24 mais próximo e aplicar o resultado no `style="height"` da própria `div`.

Precisa ser em Javascript puro, nada de Jquery.

Segue a estrutura do HTML

```
<div id="minhadiv">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis id vulputate enim. Aenean venenatis magna non nisl elementum, a pellentesque metus semper. Integer porta diam consectetur, pretium odio sit amet, euismod urna. Quisque vel dui nec ligula iaculis malesuada et nec magna. Donec turpis nulla, viverra id sem nec, malesuada dictum leo.
</div>
```

A `div` possui um `height: auto`, porém ela precisa ter a altura arredondada em múltiplos de 24 já que o conteúdo é dinâmico.

Por exemplo: se o conteúdo da `div` deixou ela com `40px` de altura, então o script deverá deixa-la com `48px` de altura, que é o múltiplo de 24 mais próximo (24*2 = 48px).

Aí ficaria assim:

```
<div id="minhadiv" style="height: 48px">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis id vulputate enim. Aenean venenatis magna non nisl elementum, a pellentesque metus semper. Integer porta diam consectetur, pretium odio sit amet, euismod urna. Quisque vel dui nec ligula iaculis malesuada et nec magna. Donec turpis nulla, viverra id sem nec, malesuada dictum leo.
</div>
```

Agora caso a `div` ficasse com `54px` de altura, o script também deixaria com `48px` (conforme o arredondamento para múltiplos de 24). Nesse caso, a `div` já possui no arquivo CSS o `overflow: auto`, já que o conteúdo vai ultrapassar o tamanho que o script definiu.

Comment: A parte do ajuste em si não é tão complicada, porém faltam alguns detalhes na sua pergunta. A técnica para resolver isto depende de uma série de fatores, principalmente de onde se encontra a div a ser alterada. Ajustar a altura por si só pode dar um monte de efeitos em cascata no layout todo, inclusive com problemas com barras de rolagem, se afetar toda a página. Teria como por a estrutura básica do html?

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta @Bacco, eu editei a pergunta, veja lá.

Answer (score 5):

Você pode usar estes dois para pegar a altura da `div`:

```
var alturaAtual = document.getElementById('teste').clientHeight;
```

ou

```
var alturaAtual = document.getElementById('teste').offsetHeight;
```

a diferença do `offsetHeight` para o `clientHeight` é que ele retorna a altura incluindo o `padding`, `border` e `scrollbar`. Você deve analisar qual é melhor para sua situação.

Eu não sei ao certo o que você quer mas fiz uma função para alterar a altura em múltiplos de 24.

CÓDIGO HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <div id="teste" style="height: 65px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

SCRIPT [ATUALIZADO]

```
function mudaAltura(idDiv) {
    var alturaAtual = document.getElementById(idDiv).offsetHeight;
    if (alturaAtual % 24 !== 0) {
        var resultado = parseInt(alturaAtual / 24);
        var novaAltura = 24 * (resultado + 1);
        document.getElementById('teste').style.height = novaAltura + "px";
    }
}
```

Ai você chama a função setando o ID da DIV como parâmetro. Ex.: `mudaAltura("minhaid");`

Comment: Coloquei seu código no [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rLyLvkjL/) funcionou direitinho.

Comment: Perfeito! Funcionou que foi uma maravilha, estou salvo!
Obrigado @williamhk2

Comment: Que bom que ajudou! :D

Comment: Boa solução! Tenho apenas uma sugestão: seria melhor alterar o `style.height` em vez de usar `setAttribute`, assim você não sobrescreve eventuais estilos já existentes na div.

Comment: Uai, fiz alguns testes aqui no jsfiddle que o @Euler01 fez e nao sobrescreveu os estilos.Neste caso, sobrescreve somente o height para a nova altura.

Comment: É que os estilos dele estão todos no CSS. Se houver mais algum estilo inline, o seu código sobrescreve (já que reescreve o atributo style inteiro).

Comment: Ah, Entendi. Vou colocar uma outra opção na resposta. valeu @bfavaretto!

Comment: Código atualizado.

Comment: Teria como uma versão deste código trabalhar com classe ao invés de ID @williamhk2?

Comment: Vou verificar aqui

Comment: @Boçal pesquisei bem aqui na internet mas não encontrei um modo de trabalhar alterando a altura de um elemento usando classe. Até fiz alguns testes com o getElementsbyClassName mas não consigo obter a altura da div ou alterá-la através deste método. Você pode ate colocar uma id com o mesmo nome da classe que está usando somente para não dar problema no código, mas acredito que não seria uma prática recomendada.